# Tomcat: define security-constraints in context.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml, security-constraint

Similar to [Define a <security-constraint> outside of web.xml (e.g. server-wide)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242619/define-a-security-constraint-outside-of-web-xml-e-g-server-wide), I am trying to define a security-constraint outside of my application's WEB-INF/web.xml.  However, unlike that question, I don't want to define it server-wide.  I have tried to put the security-constraints in both `META-INF/context.xml` and `${catalina.home}/conf/Catalina/localhost/<myapp>.xml`.  Adding the security-constraints to `${catalina.home}/conf/web.xml` works fine, but this does it for everything on the server, and I am trying to avoid this if possible.

I can't find any documentation that says definitively security-constraints must be defined in a `web.xml`, but this seems to be the case.  Is this true?

Comment: Tomcat, among other containers, implements the requirements of the servlet spec. That spec says that security-constraints go in web.xml. There's really no reason for a servlet container to implement any other strategy than that. Why do you want to configure security *outside* of the application?

Comment: Well, I'm really looking for an analog to jetty's `override-web.xml`.  I want the web app to have no security-constraints by default, but have the ability to enable them by copying in a file or something similar.  Trying to avoid having to edit an in-place web.xml.

Comment: Tomcat does not have anything like that. There is a conceptual problem with layering-on security constraints after the fact: an application needs to know which pages are protected in order to make sane decisions about the state of a request, etc. By separating the security constraints from the application, you are creating the opportunity for failure. What advantage do you get from an external configuration? What disadvantage is there to modifying `web.xml` directly?

Comment: I figured as much.  I'm trying to avoid it because it's difficult to do programmatically (e.g. from a batch script).

Comment: Try using something more appropriate like Apache Ant. It has tools available that are much more powerful than batch-scripting. For example, you can execute an XSL transform to modify XML files. If you want to script modifications, how would you do it with an *external* file?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was hoping I could copy in something like override-web.xml and have that be appended to the existing web.xml.  I'll check out ant, thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49507/discussion-between-wisco-crew-and-christopher-schultz)