# Configure Tomcat 8 with LDAP realm

Tags: authentication, tomcat, ldap, jdbcrealm

I have a problem with the configuration of a LDAP server on Tomcat 8.
I have a LDAP server configured and working on a WAS 8.5 server and I would like to configure the same LDAP on Tomcat.
The WAS configuration is (translating from italian):

- User filter: (&(cn=%v)(objectclass=inetOrgPerson))
- Group filter: (&(cn=%v)(|(objectclass=groupOfNames)(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)))
- User ID map: *:cn
- Group ID map: *:cn
- Map ID member of group: ibm-allGroups:member;ibm-allGroups:uniqueMember;groupOfNames:member;groupOfUniqueNames:uniqueMember

The Realm tag in server.xml on tomcat is:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="10"
                            connectionURL="ldap://192.168.0.3:389"
                            userBase="o=organization,c=it"
                            userSearch="(cn={0})"
                            userSubtree="true"
                            connectionName="cn=test,cn=Directory Administrators,o=organization,c=it"
                            connectionPassword="testpass"                          
            />
```

How can I fill the Realm tag with the role attributes?
And in the web.xml, what role I have to specify? I just want to grant access to all authenticated users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are already well on your way to authenticate users with the above settings.

**Roles**

For roles/groups, you can translate the WAS settings as follows:

```
<...your config...
 roleBase="o=organization,c=it"
 roleSubtree="true"
 roleSearch="(&(uniqueMember={0})(|(objectclass=groupOfNames)(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)))" 
 roleName="cn"/>
```

The roles that a user is assigned in Tomcat, will then be a list of group names from the directory. As this may vary, you will need to set up a number of groups beforehand which are listed in your web.xml. Assigning those groups to users will then give them the appropriate access.

**Authenticated Users**

If you just want to allow any authenticated user, you can set the attribute `allRolesMode` to `authOnly` like this:

```
<...your config...
 allRolesMode="authOnly"/>
```

Your web.xml should then use `*` for the role specification like this:

```
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

Maybe you should also set the `security-role` element as indicated here: [Tomcat security constraint for valid user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089600/tomcat-security-constraint-for-valid-user)

Personally I have no setup which uses `authOnly` but I know it can be done and have seen it in action.

Comment: Which did you apply? The groups approach or the allRolesMode? (btw you can mark an answer as 'accepted' when the solution works ;-) )

Comment: With this roleSearch I get following error:

 The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Comment: I think the rolesearch should be rather

(&amp;(uniqueMember={0})(|(objectclass=groupOfNames)(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)))

Comment: @ArturLinhart Yes, good catch, it is an XML file of course.